# Cast from Abstract Parent Class to Child Class

Tags: c++

I have this code,

```
class IFoo
{
 public:
   IFoo(){}
   virtual ~IFoo(){}
   virtual void fooFunc() = 0;
};

class Foo : public IFoo
{
 public:
    Foo(){}
    virtual ~Foo(){}
    virtual void fooFunc(){/*impl*/}
};

class Poop : public IFoo
{
 public:
    Poop(){}
    virtual ~Poop(){}
    virtual void fooFunc(){/*impl*/}
};

class Bar
{
 public:
    Bar(){}
    ~Bar(){}
    void setFoo(Foo* foo){/*impl*/}
};

//in main
Poop* poop = new Poop;
Bar bar;
bar.setFoo(poop);

delete poop;
```

Compiling this code gives me an error message about invalid conversion. What kind of casting should I use for this?

Please advise. Many thanks!

Comment: `Poop` inherits from `IFoo`; `Foo` also inherits from `IFoo` - there is no connection here between `Foo*` and `Poop*` in the context of `Bar::setFoo(Foo* foo)`

Answer (score 1):

`Poop` does not derive from `Foo`, so you cannot pass a `Poop*` where a `Foo*` is expected, and vice versa.  `Poop` and `Foo` both derive from `IFoo` so you need to instead change `setFoo()` to accept an `IFoo*` instead of a `Foo*`:

```
void setFoo(IFoo* foo){/*impl*/}
```